# Inserting a new page to ToC in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, memoir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force ToC not to end with a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17071/how-can-i-force-toc-not-to-end-with-a-chapter)

Does anyone know a way of adding a `\newpage` (or similar) to the ToC. One of my chapter headings is at the bottom of a page and I'd like to drop it down to start off the next page. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to "sneak" a `\newpage` into the ToC using `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}`. Here is a minimal example showing the difference - bottom 2-page layout shows the addition of the `\newpage`:

[image: \newpage in \tableofcontents]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage} % Adds \newpage in "\tableofcontents"
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}\section{A section}
\end{document}
​
```

It is usually required to `\protect` entries going into the ToC (or any external file, in general). For more on this, you should read [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764)