# Tocloft: Make a 'pagebreak' (vertical skip between chapters)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I force ToC not to end with a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17071/how-can-i-force-toc-not-to-end-with-a-chapter)

I started using `tocloft` which changed formatting and spacing in my ToC a little. I have fixed other issues, but this one remains: before `tocloft`, chapter 5 got typeset on the next page of ToC as a whole. That was very convenient as it is the last and most important chapter. But now it goes like this:

[image: tocloft]

My simple code:

```
\documentclass{mythesis}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% generate ToC
\pagenumbering{gobble} % ban page numbering
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

My question: Is there a way to 'force a pagebreak' in ToC so chapter 5 was not cut into two halves any more?